# Паттерны проектирования (программирования)

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите что почитать о паттернах (изучаю .NET)? Пришёл к выводу, что в этом надо разобраться, но не знаю откуда взять хорошую информацию.

Comment: @Gardes Там по паттернам имеется одна книга (Мартин), я читал о ней не самые лестные отзывы (хотя опять же, я эту область не знаю и могу ошибаться). Решил, вдруг помимо неё есть что-то ещё, что можно почитать.
Тот вопрос раньше не видел, поэтому приношу извинения за дубликат.

Comment: [https://proglib.io/p/design-patterns/](https://proglib.io/p/design-patterns/)

Comment: @alladuh, начните с "Паттерны проектирования (2011) - Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Фримен", там на java, но это непринципиально, java-специфичного там практически нет ничего

Comment: @slippyk Спасибо!

Comment: А как же классика - Банда Четырех, "Паттерны проектирования"

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Вот slippyk дал ссылку, там есть эта книга.

Comment: Если Вы только _изучаете_ .NET, а не являетесь программистом с некоторым опытом, то я не рекомендую читать книгу по паттернам — только голову забьёте информацией, которая Вам сейчас не очень нужна.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский интересно, вы сами то осилили ее полностью? Или бросили после первых 3-4 глав? Не, ну правда? Эта книга явно не годится с точки зрения доходчивости подачи материала (фактически это же диссертационная работа, а не учебник). Удивительно, как все же люди склонны рождать кумиров, идолов и проч. хрень и готовы бездумно покланяться им.

Comment: @Bulson а что можете посоветовать? Я так понял, вы, разбираетесь в этой теме.

Comment: @Bulson Тут Вы правы, я пробовал ее начать читать как художественную книгу: от корки до корки, но, конечно, бросил. Но заглядывал в нее при чтении других книг (типа совершенного кода), в которых авторы ну очень любят ссылаться на нее. Так, кстати, легче усваивать, сразу видно, где стоит применить, и по ссылке смотришь, КАК это делать.